# Close custom modal by jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**I want to remove my modal after click outside modal**

```
 $("#rightsidebar").removeClass("active");
```

//**I tried this**

```
  $(window).click(function(e) {
     var cd = $('#rightsidebar').hasClass('active');
     var cf = $('#rightsidebar').val();
    if(e.target.id == cf){
        $("#rightsidebar").removeClass("active");

    }
    // if(cd == true){

    // }else{

    // }
    // if(){
    //     alert("hai");
    // }else{
    //     alert("nahi hai")
    // }
    // alert(e.target.id); // gives the element's ID 
    //alert(e.target.className); // gives the elements class(es)
});
```

//html code is below

```
<aside id="rightsidebar" class="right-sidebar notification active">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#setting">Notifications</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active slideRight" id="setting">
            <div class="slimScrollDiv" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: calc(100vh - 70px);"><div class="slim_scroll" style="overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: calc(100vh - 70px);">
                <div class="card">
                    <ul class="setting-list list-unstyled">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="icon pink-bg"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-notifications"></i></span>
                                Blood Pressure test reminder
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="icon green-bg"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-notifications"></i></span>
                                Hospital Accepted your profile edit request
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm edit">Edit</button>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="icon pink-bg"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-notifications"></i></span>
                                Doctor visit completed
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="icon pink-bg"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-notifications"></i></span>
                                Blood Pressure test reminder
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="icon green-bg"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-notifications"></i></span>
                                Hospital Accepted your profile edit request
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm edit">Edit</button>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="icon pink-bg"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-notifications"></i></span>
                                Blood Pressure test reminder
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="icon green-bg"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-notifications"></i></span>
                                Hospital Accepted your profile edit request
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm edit">Edit</button>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="icon pink-bg"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-notifications"></i></span>
                                Doctor visit completed
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div><div class="slimScrollBar" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); width: 2px; position: absolute; top: 0px; opacity: 0.4; display: none; border-radius: 3px; z-index: 99; right: 1px; height: 168.6px;"></div><div class="slimScrollRail" style="width: 2px; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; display: none; border-radius: 0px; background: rgb(51, 51, 51); opacity: 0.2; z-index: 90; right: 1px;"></div></div>                
        </div>       
    </div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a general solution to do something when clicking outside of the element:

```js
$(window).click(function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target);
  if (!$target.closest('#rightsidebar').length) {
     $("#rightsidebar").removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
#rightsidebar:not(.active) {
   display: none;
}
```

In this code, I assume that your modal is `#rightsidebar`

Comment: In this modal with active class modal show with remove modal hide

Comment: @PkPrajapati sorry I don't understand, but the accepted answer removed the wrong answer and add my solution.

Comment: @PkPrajapati I've added a bit of CSS you don't need two classes to show/hide the modal. I thought that you know how to hide the modal, and only need a solution on how to click outside.